# Why do I get an Recursion error whenever i am deleting a letter from a modified stirng And how do I solve it?

Tags: recursion, pygame

I am trying to make a choice game where you can write and rewrite a name of the character in the game but whenever I try to delete a letter whilst testing the code I get an Recursion error
What is the cause to this problem and how to avoid it?

Here is my code

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
import time
win = pg.display.set_mode((900,600))
pg.display.set_caption("Choices")
go = 0
user_text = ''
lbrown = 225, 156, 0
brown = 192, 128, 0
dbrown = 128, 64, 0
black = 0, 0, 0
dgrey = 64, 64, 64
grey = 128,128,128
lgrey = 192,192,192
white = 255, 255, 255
red = 255, 0, 0
orange = 255,128,0
yellow = 255,223,0
lgreen = 128,255,0
green = 0,255,0
dgreen = 0,128,0
turcoise = 0,192,128
lblue = 0,128,255
blue = 0,0,255
dblue = 0,0,128
blurple = 128,0,192
purple = 192,0,192
pirple = 167, 0, 167
rpink = 255,0,128
pink = 255,0,255
startclick = 0

class BG(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface([400,100])
        self.image.fill(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class START(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface([200,100])
        self.image.fill(green)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class START_TEXT(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render('Start',False, pink)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()



bg = BG()
bg.rect.x = 25
bg.rect.y = 100

start = START()
start.rect.x = 450
start.rect.y = 260

start_txt = START_TEXT()
start_txt.rect.x = 495
start_txt.rect.y = 280

all_sprite = pg.sprite.Group()
all_sprite.add(start,start_txt)


win.fill(purple)

def redraw():
    all_sprite.draw(win)
    pg.display.update()

run = True
while run:
    pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
    print(startclick)


    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

        if start.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            start.image.fill(dgreen)
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                startclick = 1

                win.fill(black)
                all_sprite.remove(start,start_txt)
        else:
            start.image.fill(green)

        key = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pg.K_BACKSPACE]:
            all_sprite.remove(bg, user_text)
            user_text = user_text[:-1]

            go = 1
        else:
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                user_text += event.unicode
            usertex = user_text

        class User_TxT(pg.sprite.Sprite):
            def __init__(self):
                pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
                self.image = font.render(usertex, True, pink)
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        user_txt = User_TxT()
        user_txt.rect.x = 70
        user_txt.rect.y = 120

        if startclick == 1:
            all_sprite.add(bg, user_txt)



    pg.display.flip()
    redraw()
quit()
pg.quit()
```

And the Recursion Error

```
packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 471, in
    if isinstance(sprite, Sprite):        
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your `User_TxT` sprite class to support an update function to change its text. This will prevent the need to remove and recreate the sprite which causes your recursion error.

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
import time
win = pg.display.set_mode((900,600))
pg.display.set_caption("Choices")
go = 0
user_text = ''
lbrown = 225, 156, 0
brown = 192, 128, 0
dbrown = 128, 64, 0
black = 0, 0, 0
dgrey = 64, 64, 64
grey = 128,128,128
lgrey = 192,192,192
white = 255, 255, 255
red = 255, 0, 0
orange = 255,128,0
yellow = 255,223,0
lgreen = 128,255,0
green = 0,255,0
dgreen = 0,128,0
turcoise = 0,192,128
lblue = 0,128,255
blue = 0,0,255
dblue = 0,0,128
blurple = 128,0,192
purple = 192,0,192
pirple = 167, 0, 167
rpink = 255,0,128
pink = 255,0,255
startclick = 0

class BG(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface([400,100])
        self.image.fill(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class START(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface([200,100])
        self.image.fill(green)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class START_TEXT(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render('Start',False, pink)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class User_TxT(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, usertex):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.update(usertex)
    
    def update(self, usertex):
        font = pg.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 40)
        self.image = font.render(usertex, True, pink)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

bg = BG()
bg.rect.x = 25
bg.rect.y = 100

start = START()
start.rect.x = 450
start.rect.y = 260

start_txt = START_TEXT()
start_txt.rect.x = 495
start_txt.rect.y = 280


user_txt = User_TxT(user_text)

all_sprite = pg.sprite.Group()
all_sprite.add(start,start_txt)


win.fill(purple)

def redraw():
    all_sprite.draw(win)
    pg.display.update()

run = True
while run:
    pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
    print(startclick)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

        if start.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            start.image.fill(dgreen)
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                startclick = 1

                win.fill(black)
                all_sprite.remove(start,start_txt)
        else:
            start.image.fill(green)

        key = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pg.K_BACKSPACE]:
            # all_sprite.remove(bg, user_text)
            user_text = user_text[:-1]

            go = 1
        else:
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                user_text += event.unicode
            # usertex = user_text
        user_txt.update(user_text)

        user_txt.rect.x = 70
        user_txt.rect.y = 120

        if startclick == 1:
            all_sprite.add(bg, user_txt)
            startclick = 0

    pg.display.flip()
    redraw()
quit()
pg.quit()
```

I've tried to make minimal changes to your code to avoid confusion.

EDIT to add some additional explanation:
I changed the `User_TxT` sprite class to take an input string as its initial text string to display and to also have an `update()` function so that its text string can be changed. This function is also what we need to do when initialising the sprite, so to prevent duplication, it's called from `__init__()`. That way you only need to have one sprite. You were also redefining and instantiating the `User_TxT` class for every event, which is unnecessary.

To help identify the code differences, you can use a diff tool, like [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/?lang=en) on Windows, or the command line `diff` tool on Linux.

If you run into further issues with your code, you should ask a new question, if you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much but what had to be changed in the User_TxT Class?